# SVN Unknown FS type (imported project)

Tags: linux, svn, ftp, raspberry-pi, fsfs

I have reset my Raspberry Pi (there was too much trash running). I thought I can simply use my Backup in order to make SVN running again. And here comes the problem: My Backups (Daily, fully automatic) just copied all folders and files to a FTP-Webserver. Now I just downloaded it onto my Windows-PC and copied it to the Raspberry Pi via WinSCP (first i created the folder with sudo svnadmin create) and i have deleted all existing files and folder and just replaced them with the stuff from the FTP server - Should be the same ? After that I have set the permissions and now it should work. But it doesnt - here is the problem (when trying to open the svn with google chrome) - there is this message:

```
<D:error xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:m="http://apache.org/dav/xmlns" xmlns:C="svn:">
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="160033">Could not open the requested SVN filesystem</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

The apache-error log also logs the problem:

```
[Sat Dec 05 21:37:28.826821 2015] [:error] [pid 559:tid 3003118640] (20014)Internal error: [client 192.168.188.20:55525] Unknown FS type 'fsfs\r'
[Sat Dec 05 21:37:28.831649 2015] [dav:error] [pid 559:tid 3003118640] [client 192.168.188.20:55525] Could not fetch resource information.  [500, #0]
[Sat Dec 05 21:37:28.831808 2015] [dav:error] [pid 559:tid 3003118640] [client 192.168.188.20:55525] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #160033]
[Sat Dec 05 21:37:28.831914 2015] [dav:error] [pid 559:tid 3003118640] [client 192.168.188.20:55525] Could not open the requested SVN filesystem  [500, #160033]
```

Does somebody of you have an idea what I can do to make my repositories working again ?

Many thanks in advance,
Dominik

**Update(1):**
I have fixed some files which seam to cause the problems. Now when I try to dump my repository there is the following error:

> ```
>  sudo svnadmin dump XYZ > b
>  svnadmin: E200002: Serialized hash malformed
>  ' into a number04: Could not convert '8
> ```

**Update(2)**

Now i fixed some files (seems to be problem with encoding or something like that). I got a lot of errors like the following:

```
svnadmin: E160004: Corrupt representation '10 830800 775 3124 (null) c38413b634a5c0f296b8806f46ba0d3b8f906125 (null)'
svnadmin: E160004: Malformed representation header at XYZ/db/revs/0/10:830817
```

I fixed them: Open the file deleted the space where null is (looks like a normal space ...) and made a new space (simply used windows editor). That fixes this problem **but** it only worked for the first 9 files now I get an other error:

```
svnadmin: E200002: Can't read length line in file 'XYZ/db/revs/0/10'
```

I already tried the same thing - delete the space and the last (empty line) after the length but that does not work for me. Has andybody of you an idea ?

In the future I will use dump to make a dump and save the dump to my ftp-server. But even with these modifications dump does not work - when trying to dump r 0-9 or r 1 there is the following error:

```
svnadmin: E200002: Serialized hash malformed
' into a number04: Could not convert '10
```

Thanks in advance,
Dominik

Comment: same svn version in raspberry pi before and after? Do the repos work on your windows box (with file:// protocol)?

Comment: Run `svnadmin verify` against your repositories.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's a long time that I've worked with svn so it's just a guess. I also would prefer to write this in a comment, but it's too long ;-)

As far as I know they change the fs-type with every new version. So if you installed a newer version the dpkg manager tries to convert the registered repositories. If you overwrite a generated repository with an older one this conversion does not take place. `dpkg-reconfigure <svn package name>` could possibly help. But I'm not sure.

Here is a link http://svn.apache.org/repos/asf/subversion/trunk/subversion/libsvn_fs_fs/structure pointing to the description of the fs-structure of svn. Perhaps comparing the structures and versions gives you an idea what went wrong.

Comment: I looked at the format file and in both (new created and old backup) there is just a 5. Acording to your link: "Format 5, understood by Subversion 1.7-dev, never released". And the folder structur also looks right (its the same).

Comment: Format 5 indicates that a SQLite DB is used for storage. I assume that's the reason why this format is installed on an ARM system with fewer resources. But if you say that there is no difference between the format two repositories, I would assume there is  a corrupt SQLite base. Perhaps you did not copy any dblog files because their name start with a dot (.). But the error message say something complete different. Sorry I think I can not help you any further.